# Best UI tool to use with breeze?

Tags: breeze

Can anyone recommend a UI toolset, commercial or open source, that works well with breeze.js?
I have tried kendo with knockout-kendo.js, but it doesn't play well.

thanks

Comment: I know people who are pairing Kendo with Breeze now and other who are using Data Tables with Breeze. Hoping to get you a substantive answer soon.

Comment: Are you challenged by the entire UI suite or is it grids that are holding you back? If grids, do you need editable grid or just read-only?

Comment: For me  - grids would be nice to have editable grids

Answer (score 0):

I am using slickgrid after trying datatables ,jqxGrid and KOGrid.

If you are not using Durandal then I would suggest KOGrid. It does not render well when using Durandal. If you do not intend to use Durandal then I would suggest slickgrid... the performance is just sensational. Both of these are full featured grids but slickgrid has been around longer.